# How is the RetryAfter TimeSpan calculated?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a Function that's a Service Bus trigger subscribing to a Topic that aggregates data for a particular entity (1:M), and ultimately calling a DocumentDb Stored Proc to Upsert the entities. So, for every message, let's say there's 60 entities I'm operating on (upserting).

I was spamming (I guess) CosmosDb (RUs is 400, so not very large, it's only a test Db) and started receiving `Request rate is too large` exceptions, so I investigated how to best handle it, and noticed a code example somewhere that utilized the `RetryAfter` property on `DocumentClientException` and was wondering how this property is calculated?

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.documentclientexception.retryafter?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Documents_DocumentClientException_RetryAfter) aren't exactly telling, but in the case of a Production-level incident I'd like to have that kind of information handy.

Is it some kind of Fibonacci sequence for each attempt or? Also, how does it keep track of how many attempts have already been made? (or does it?)

Comment: Are you creating your own `DocumentClient` to execute the sproc?

Comment: It’s getting passed through as a DocumentDB attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic behind the time span is explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/performance-tips#429).

When using the binding to obtain the `DocumentClient`, it is using the [default constructor](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/blob/dev/src/WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB/Services/CosmosDBService.cs#L21).

The client already retries by [default](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.connectionpolicy.retryoptions?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Documents_Client_ConnectionPolicy_RetryOptions) on `Request rate is too large` errors a set of times (9 by default).

If you want more granular or customized control, you can manage the `DocumentClient` instance yourself without the binding and set up the [MaxRetryAttemptsOnThrottledRequests](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.retryoptions.maxretryattemptsonthrottledrequests?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Documents_Client_RetryOptions_MaxRetryAttemptsOnThrottledRequests) or [MaxRetryWaitTimeInSeconds](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.retryoptions.maxretrywaittimeinseconds?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Documents_Client_RetryOptions_MaxRetryWaitTimeInSeconds).

If are going to create your own `DocumentClient`, I'd advice to make it [static](https://medium.com/@Ealsur/azure-cosmos-db-functions-cookbook-static-client-874072aef28e).

Either way, if you try/catch the `DocumentClientException`and check for `StatusCode` 429, you will be able to catch the scenarios that go beyond the `MaxRetryAttemptsOnThrottledRequests`.

For example:

```
#r "Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client"
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client;
using System.Net;
using System.Configuration;

private static string endpointUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["cosmosDBAccountEndpoint"]; 
private static string authorizationKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["cosmosDBAccountKey"]; 
private static DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endpointUrl), authorizationKey, new ConnectionPolicy() {
            RetryOptions = new RetryOptions()
            {
                MaxRetryAttemptsOnThrottledRequests = 10,
                MaxRetryWaitTimeInSeconds  = 20
            }
        });
});

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    string id = req.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
        .FirstOrDefault(q => string.Compare(q.Key, "id", true) == 0)
        .Value;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id)){
          return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    Uri documentUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri("name of database","name of collection",id);
    try {
        Document doc = await client.ReadDocumentAsync(documentUri);
    }
    catch(DocumentClientException ex){
        int statusCode = (int)ex.StatusCode;
        if (statusCode == 429) {
            // Request rate errors went over the MaxRetryAttemptsOnThrottledRequests
            // Do something you want here
        }

        throw;
    }
    if (doc == null){
      return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }

    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, doc);
}
```

Comment: So it sounds like `RetryAfter` is directly correlated with `MaxRetryWaitTimeInSeconds` property on the `RetryOptions` object? Any idea why `RetryAfter` would be a `TimeSpan` and the other an `int`?

Comment: `RetryAfter` maps the value of the `x-ms-retry-after-ms` header that tells the client when to retry. If the value of `RetryAfter` is higher than `MaxRetryWaitTimeInSeconds`, then the SDK won't retry and throw the exception. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/performance-tips#429)